# How to pre sort Firebase Database for faster performance (Android)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want my Firebase Database to be sorted right at the moment a new variable enters.
My goal is to sort an integer representing the subscriber ammount from biggest to lowest, so that when I populate my recyclerview (Top subscribed account) I don't have to check against every value in my Database.

Is there a way of doing something like that, or a way better solution to my problem?

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase database sort all the childs using alphabetical order. So using only the Firebase reference, you always get yours "Top subscribed accounts" in the alphabetical order of his Ids.

Firebase provide helpful methods to filter or order your querys. Check [firebase.database.Reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference) especially the method [orderByChild](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#orderByChild)

Making querys with the correct filtering (order), it's the way to get the Firebase data in the way you want.